# What is the determinant of the matrix $A^2+B^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two $n\times n $ matrices such that $A\neq B$, $A^3=B^3$, and $A^2B=B^2A,$  then what is the value of $\det(A^2+B^2)$ ?

My attempt: $A^3=B^3 \Rightarrow (A-B)(A^2+AB+B^2)=0 \Rightarrow A^2+AB+B^2=0$

but I can't get any idea

Comment: The last implication, per se, is false, since two matrices $X\ne 0,\ Y\ne 0$ could satisfy $XY=0$. You can infer, at most, that $\det(A^2+AB+B^2)=0$.

Comment: Be careful, there are zero divisors in matrix algebras, $A^2+AB+B^2$ needs not be $0$.

Comment: Is it an exercise that has been given to you, knowing that there is a unique answer ?

Comment: By the way, in the comments to a now deleted answer, I think you suggested the answer had to be chosen between four real numbers. That could not be the case (unless the answer was $0$), since for all pairs $A,B$ satisfying the hypothesis, so does the pair $\lambda A, \lambda B$, for which the answer is $\lambda^{2n} \det(A^2+B^2)$.

Answer (score 2):

First a couple of notes on your attempt:

$$(A-B)(A^2+AB+B^2) = A^3+A^2B+AB^2-BA^2-BAB-B^3$$

and if $A$ and $B$ do not commute, it doesn't need to be $A^3-B^3$. You have to be careful about factorization in non-commutative rings, familiar formulas do not always work.

Even it were true, as I already said in comments, $$((A-B)(A^2+AB+B^2) = 0\ \wedge\ A\neq B)\ \nRightarrow\ A^2 +AB + B^2 = 0$$

This is because there are [zero divisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor) in matrix algebra (there are examples in the link).

---

Now, to the solution:

$$(A^2+B^2)A = A^3 + B^2A = B^3 +A^2B = (A^2 + B^2)B \implies (A^2 + B^2)(A-B) = 0$$

Now, if $\det(A^2 + B^2) \neq 0$, then $A^2 + B^2$ is invertible, but then $A-B = 0$ which is contradiction. Hence, $\det (A^2 + B^2) = 0$.

Comment: This could be easily guessed to be true from the comment by G. Sassatelli, about $\lambda A$ and $\lambda B$ satisfying all the requirements as $A$ and $B$, but $\det((\lambda A)^2 + (\lambda B)^2)\neq \det(A^2 + B^2)$ for $|\lambda|\neq 1$, unless the determinant is $0$.